# Submit a button with curl

Tags: video, curl, hyperlink

I would get the source of a webpage that's hide behind a POST request.
The site is Putlocker (Same as Sockshare) and this is an example link http://www.putlocker.com/file/09B928FA1007844E

I need to click on the `Continue as free user` button and then get the HTTP Source to get video's link.